# How to insert a value for a particular column in mysql while performing Sqoop Export

Tags: sqoop

I run a command which exports data from my HDFS to MySql.

But I want to **insert** data to particular columns at run time, while running the Export Command.

Is this possible?

Or if not, is there any work-around to achieve this?

My command would be like this:

`bin/sqoop export --connect jdbc:mysql://my ip/test --username uname --password pwd --table table name --export-dir /MR/part-r-00000 --input-fields-terminated-by ',' --verbose -m 1`

(**Here I want to supply data for certain columns**).

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you can take advantage of parameter --columns to specify subset of table's columns that are available in the input files.

Comment: Hi Jarek,
My problem is that i already have the entire data as sequence file, and i'm currently passing null values for some of the fields. I want to substitute the curdate for that field. I can't use the null substitution since other columns may get affected. I cant use --column since i want the entire data. I tried writing Stored Proc but that is not helping since i can't use both --table and --call in same command. I just wanna substitute values for only one field. How this can be achieved.